# Where am I supposed to get an I2C BUFFER_LENGTH defined?

Tags: programming, i2c

I am using a BLE nano - as soon as I try to include I2Cdev.h and compile, I get this error:

```
Arduino\libraries\I2Cdev\I2Cdev.cpp:276:62: error: 'BUFFER_LENGTH' was not declared in this scope
```

How should I fix this? I imagine I can hard-code it in and guess around as to the value (32 seems common), but I think I am missing something else as far as it using the right libraries for the hardware, so how can I check/fix that if it is indeed the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BUFFER_LENGTH is set in [I2Cdev.h](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/I2Cdev/I2Cdev.h) depending on the target. BLE nano is not directly supported (what I can see).

Cheers!